# Google Play push notification for app update available not being sent reliably. Am I missing something?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play, upgrade

Me and my team recently published an app on Google Play. My knowledge tells me that all I need to do is to change the versionCode in the AndroidManifest.xml file everytime I upload the new APK and from there, Google Play does the job of notifying the users about an available update. I am in touch with many real world users who say they never got a notification about app update despite the several updates we have published to the original app. I know that there are certain device level playstore settings such as "Update app only on wi-fi" etc. and I've verified all such combinations of scenarios. I still believe that all the users are not notified about the new version available. So my questions are
1) Am I missing anything in the first place?
2) What are my options to make sure the user gets notified about the available update?

Comment: If the users have selected the option of Auto update in their mobile devices then app will be updated automatically or else they will have to update manually if option is unchecked.

Comment: If the new version is no longer compatible with the device (for example when the `minSdkVersion` has changed) the users with old devices will not get notified.

Comment: @Henry, Thanks for your reply. My app is compatible for OS version 2.3+. One of the members in my team had a device with OS version 4.2.2. She had an older version of my app. When she launched Google Play page for our app, the only options (green buttons) she saw were Open and Uninstall. Ideally, it should have been Update and Uninstall. I thought that same, that my newer app is not compatible with her OS version. I asked her to uninstall the existing app and then install it again from playstore. This time, she got the latest version. Isn't that strange. I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: How long did you wait? It can take a few hours until the new version is visible.

Comment: I am not sure but if you change the permissions needed for your application when updating it, your real world users won't get the new version automatically. Anyway when I upload a new version it takes about a day to the users to get notified.

Comment: @Henry - Thanks again. It's been a few days that the latest version of the app has been published and available to other users.

Comment: @zozelfelfo -  I only changed the permissions of the app once but after that I have made at least 4 more releases. Plus, are you sure changing the permissions does this? What could be reason behind this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1006072 anytime you change the application permissions your app wont be installed automatically, this is because the user has the right to read the new permission set and decide if he accept it or not.

Comment: @zozelfelfo - I am not expecting the app to be updated automatically (after my permissions were changed). However, will google play send them an 'update avilable' notification ?

Comment: That should happen, but only once and probably the notification will group some app not only yours

Answer (score 0):

You can not reliably tell when your user will get notified. Update notifications are dependant on battery status, network availability, user activity and compatibility.